# Netcat command: Unknown IP address

Tags: windows, macos, netcat

I have two laptops that each has connected to the Internet by landline (two different lines/modem). One is Mac and the other is Windows. I want to send a message from Windows to the Mac.

1. I installed `NetCat` on Mac using, `brew install netcat`, based on [this page](https://brewformulas.org/netcat).
2. I installed `NetCat` on Windows based on [this page](https://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows/).
3. I ran following command in Mac terminal in order to see what is my IP address: `$ ipconfig getifaddr en0` it printed: `169.254.136.39`
4. In Mac terminal: `$ nc -u -l -p 4444`. Seems it is ready for incomming messages.
5. In Windows terminal: `$ nc -u 169.254.136.39 4444`. I get a new line and I assume connection has established. However, when I enter a message and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing happens :(

When I replace above command with `nc -u -v -n 169.254.136.39 4444` in Windows and `nc -u -l -n -p 4444` in Mac, then I get: `(UNKNOWN) [169.254.136.39] 4444 (?) open`

I have no idea what is wrong? I confirm Firewal is off on my Mac.

Comment: The port needs to be open on the router going to the incoming ip as well.